# php contact form doesn't work when user supplies non-working return email address

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have a PHP contact form that sends the form data to me only when the user supplies a valid return email address (the email is formatted correctly, it just isn't a valid working email.) I'm not able to see any of the other data they provided, i.e., name, phone number, or comment. It just never gets to me. Is this how things normally work? Does the email system actually check a validly formatted email address can actually send/receive email?

Comment: Can you please provide some code for us to check.  What is it that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could verify it's a proper email like this:

```
$result = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if ($result == TRUE) {
   //is an email
   } else {
   //not an email
}
```

[filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

[validation filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)